# Javascript to check if a CSS class is on the page without Jquery

Tags: javascript, css

I'm looking for a cross-browser compatible and lightweight way to check to see if any instance of a CSS class is on a page or not.

For example, if I want to check for 'myclass', and  or  was anywhere on the page, then it would return true, else false.

I've tried a function like this, but it does not work:

```
function getElementsByClassName( clsName ) 
{ 
    var arr = new Array(); 
    var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for ( var cls, i = 0; ( elem = elems[i] ); i++ )
    {
        if ( elem.className == clsName )
        {
            arr[arr.length] = elem;
        }
    }
    return arr;
} 
if ( getElementsByClassName('myclass').length >= 1) { 
    // yes, it's on the page
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You mean if there is any element in the DOM that has the class you are looking for? Also can you elaborate on the "does not work" part?

Comment: Yes, and it returns an empty array even if the class is on the page.  And to clarify cross-browser, I was thinking back to at least IE6 and the last 2-3 versions of other browsers. Just trying to get 99% of users. If it can fail gracefully, that's ok too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/sK2zd/

I just changed your code a little, but it's doing what you expect.

```
function getElementsByClassName(clsName) {
    var arr = [];
    var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        if (elems[i].className == clsName) {
            arr.push(elems[i]);
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

window.onload = function () {
    var all_classes = getElementsByClassName('testing');
    if (all_classes.length > 0) {
        // yes, it's on the page
        alert("Found " + all_classes.length + " element(s) with class 'testing'");
    } else {
        alert("Found none");
    }
};
```

UPDATE:

Looking back at this answer I realized I never suggested `elems[i].className == clsName` probably isn't correct, as the `className` property may be several classes separated by a space character. So there would need to be a better way to see if it has a class.

Comment: I think my issue was not checking for onload first, so it was not finding it.  I'll have to find a workaround for that since my clients could already have an onload check on their page.  Maybe something like this: http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/onloads/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the more fleshed out example and fiddle.

Comment: Ahh I hadn't thought of that, I assumed the part where you called the function was just an example of use, and was not actually called right after declaring the function. Glad I could help in some way :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [querySelector method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelector) much like jQuery selectors

Comment: But it isn't cross-browser-versions :)

Comment: Ah, obviously I didn't make my point clearly enough: my question was regarding the fact that `document.querySelector()` and `document.querySelectorAll()` isn't fully-supported cross-browser (although it's *far* better supported than I previously though: [Quirksmode Compatibility reference](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t13).

Answer (score 1):

In HTML5 you can use [document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) with [CSS3 selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/).

```
if (document.querySelectorAll('.the_class_name').length > 0) {
  doIt();
}
```

Comment: OP asked for a cross-browser solution. This obviously isn't.

Comment: How it isn't cross-browser? `document.querySelector()` and `document.querySelectorAll()` is supported by FF from 3.5, IE 8, Opera 10 and Webkit 3.2

Comment: @JanHančič Cross-browser isn't defined in black and white. CQQL's solution has decent browser support.

Comment: IE7&6 do not support it. Granted the OP did not define exactly which browsers need to be supported.

Comment: I was thinking back to at least IE6 and the last 2-3 versions of other browsers.  Just trying to get 99% of users.  If it can fail gracefully, that's ok too.

Comment: IE6 has 11 years and in August it has 0.5%, IE 7 has 6 years and 1.8% (according to http://tinyurl.com/2adzxr) so in total you are loosing up to 2.5% of the people. 
Statcounter for the last month do not even show IE6 and IE7 shows at 1.22% (http://tinyurl.com/cn6lufq). Those browsers are dead.

Comment: When one of your clients is a bank, their IE 6 use is much higher than the norm.  Like I said, if it were to fail gracefully and not throw a JS error, that is fine too. Anyway, question answered and accepted and I'll work it out from here, thanks.